# how to implements service provider for saml2 sso without private key

Tags: single-sign-on

I have a customer who wants to implement SAML2 SSO, the customer will be the Identity Provider (IDP) and my web application will effectively be the Service Provider (SP).

But my customer only give me the certificate file (.crt) and metadata xml file, and i checked the openSAML code which need SPKeystore.jks to initialize KeyStore Object.

So how to implements the service provider without the .jks file? 
Is the jks file necessary ?
who know it, thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks rdmueller and iadd.  Now I create the keystore (jks) file, but the alias and the password is required, so we need to ask our customer for the alias and password?

Answer (score 0):

you create the keystore (jks) yourself and add the certificate to it. In a java environment, you use the `keytool` for doing so.

Comment: so I also need the alias and password of the certificate, yes?

Comment: you can select the alias by yourself.

Comment: regarding the password: it depends on the certificate and the use of the certificate. it could even be rhat the password is empty.

Comment: When I import the crt file into the jks file, it always ask for a password. When I enter the password, the prompt password doesn't match.
`keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Public keys in reply and keystore don't match`

Comment: do you use the right password? there is one for the keystore and one for the certificate...

Comment: I tried various methods and still did not solve it.That can I don't use the jks file to get verification info from IDP? Only used a signed metadata xml file?   Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you make any progress? Can you describe in more detail (update your question) where you are stuck? What Did you try?

Comment: IDP tell me there is no password for .crt file, we only set keystore password by -storepass parameter, and here is springsecurity config file:

Comment: <bean id="keyManager" class="org.springframework.security.saml.key.JKSKeyManager">
        <constructor-arg value="classpath:security/keystore.jks"/>
        <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="111111"/>
        <constructor-arg>
            <map>
                <entry key="zoom" value="111111"/>
                <entry key="roche" value="111111"/>
            </map>
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="zoom"/>
    </bean>

Comment: rdmueller, thanks for your great help on it, but now the problem is still open, I create another question paper to describe the full problems, could you please take a look on it, thanks a lot! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52378630/how-to-use-spring-saml-code-with-jks-or-signed-metdata

Comment: and there is my new questions.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52378630/how-to-use-spring-saml-code-with-jks-or-signed-metdata

Answer (score 0):

You can use `keytool` import certificate file into `SPKeystore.jks`

```
keytool -import -alias <alias> -trustcacerts -file <xx.crt> -keystore SPKeystore.jks -storepass <SPKeystorePassPhrase>
```