# How to use Spring SAML code with jks or signed metdata

Tags: java, spring-mvc, saml-2.0, opensaml, spring-security-saml2

The IDP only provided .crt file and metadata xml file, and IDP told us there is no password for .crt file, I created jks file with command：keytool -import -alias zoom  -trustcacerts -file qa.crt  -keystore keystory.jks.
Now,I downloaded the spring SAML demo code, and changed the securiyContext.xml as bellow:

--------matadata.xml---------------------

```
<md:EntityDescriptor entityID="gene.com" cacheDuration="PT1440M" ID="dfhGJ7yKW7C3nvicVEN.puf7bSh" xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata">
<ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
        <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
        <ds:Reference URI="#dfhGJ7yKW7C3nvicVEN.puf7bSh">
            <ds:Transforms>
                <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
                <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
            </ds:Transforms>
            <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
            <ds:DigestValue>lSCVZb+3JcGXnhwYj5IQqxaM2UaBbmiTOYa/fO5NRAo=</ds:DigestValue>
        </ds:Reference>
    </ds:SignedInfo>
    <ds:SignatureValue>
        {my ds:SignatureValue}
    </ds:SignatureValue>
    <ds:KeyInfo>
        <ds:X509Data>
            <ds:X509Certificate>
                {my ds:X509Certificate}
            </ds:X509Certificate>
        </ds:X509Data>
        <ds:KeyValue>
            <ds:RSAKeyValue>
                <ds:Modulus>
                    {my ds:Modulus}
                </ds:Modulus>
                <ds:Exponent>AQAB</ds:Exponent>
            </ds:RSAKeyValue>
        </ds:KeyValue>
    </ds:KeyInfo>
</ds:Signature>
<md:IDPSSODescriptor protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <md:KeyDescriptor use="signing">
        <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <ds:X509Data>
                <ds:X509Certificate>
                    {my ds:X509Certificate}
                </ds:X509Certificate>
            </ds:X509Data>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
    </md:KeyDescriptor>
    <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified</md:NameIDFormat>
    <md:SingleSignOnService Location="https://b2bqa.roche.com/idp/SSO.saml2" Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"/>
    <md:SingleSignOnService Location="https://b2bqa.roche.com/idp/SSO.saml2" Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect"/>
    <saml:Attribute NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic" Name="WorkPhone" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"/>
    <saml:Attribute NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic" Name="ChrisID" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"/>
    <saml:Attribute NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic" Name="Email" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"/>
    <saml:Attribute NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic" Name="Account" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"/>
    <saml:Attribute NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic" Name="Department" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"/>
    <saml:Attribute NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic" Name="MobilePhone" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"/>
    <saml:Attribute NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic" Name="Sex" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"/>
</md:IDPSSODescriptor>
<md:ContactPerson contactType="administrative">
    <md:Company>Genentech Inc.,</md:Company>
    <md:GivenName>IAM-DFS</md:GivenName>
    <md:EmailAddress>GLOORG_SAS-AMS-Web-Access-Services-Comms@msxdl.roche.com</md:EmailAddress>
</md:ContactPerson>
```

---

```
<bean id="samlMetadataManager" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.CachingMetadataManager">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean id="samlRocheIDP" class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.FilesystemMetadataProvider">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <value type="java.io.File">classpath:qa.xml</value>
                </constructor-arg>
                <property name="parserPool" ref="samlParserPool"/>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

--------------securiyContext.xml--------------------
But there is always failed where SP initialize, error message:

```
Signature verification failed.
Signature trust establishment failed for metadata entry https://b2b.roche.com
Error filtering metadata from E:\Workspace2\saml\spring-security-saml\target\classes\qa.xml
```

And my question is that how to integration the spring saml with signed metadata xml file. should i create another jks file? I have cloned many java demos, they have configured metadata xml files and jks files in **springWebSecurityContext.xml** .

But I think the metadata xml already contains the certificate and the secret key. I don't think I need to configure the jks file anymore, right?

Can you help me find out how to integrate saml into my project? Thank you everyone!

Comment: `JKSKeyManager(Resource storeFile, String storePass, Map<String, String> passwords, String defaultKey)`

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have proper .jks file . You will need a bean for keyManager.

```
@Bean
public KeyManager keyManager() {
    DefaultResourceLoader loader = new DefaultResourceLoader();
    Resource storeFile = loader
        .getResource("classpath:/saml/keystore.jks");
    String storePass = "nalle123";
    Map<String, String> passwords = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String defaultKey = "apollo";
    passwords.put("apollo", "nalle123");
    return new JKSKeyManager(storeFile, storePass, passwords, defaultKey);
}
```

You can have multiple keys and password for this in Map but it need one as default. This bean is also used by MetadataGenerator bean

You can import certificate in keystore , below script can be used

```
IDP_HOST=<hostip>
IDP_PORT=<port>
CERTIFICATE_FILE=certfile.cert
KEYSTORE_FILE=keystore.jks
KEYSTORE_PASSWORD=<password>

openssl s_client -host $IDP_HOST -port $IDP_PORT -prexit -showcerts </dev/null | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > $CERTIFICATE_FILE
keytool.exe -delete -alias <put alias name here> -keystore $KEYSTORE_FILE -storepass $KEYSTORE_PASSWORD
keytool.exe -import -alias <put alias name here> -file $CERTIFICATE_FILE - 
keystore $KEYSTORE_FILE -storepass $KEYSTORE_PASSWORD -noprompt
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I still don't understand what 'nalle123' and 'apollo' stand for.
That i create .jks file with alias 'roche' and with password '111111'.then i import crt file into the jks file with alias 'zoom' and password '111111'.
What should i config the storepass 、passwords and defaultKey ?

Comment: Have you ever configured TLSProtocolConfigurer yet? when i enable the TLSProtocolConfigurer ,my program is getting an error.

Comment: apollo is key and nalle123 is password for .jks file . This is the alias name and password form script  
I have not used TLSProtocolConfigurer.
if it works for you can you please mark it as appropriate answer

Comment: sure , Thank you very much.